# How to get the output every day with the incrementation of the days

Tags: java, spring-boot

I did this Java component to insert 2 rows in the database every day at 1:00 Am.
I know `date.plusDays(1)` function to increment the dates but I don't know how to use it to increment the date every time the insert made.

```
@Component
public class ScheduledPlans {

 private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new
 SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");


 private final Logger log =
  LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledPlans.class);


 @Autowired
 PlanServiceImpl planDao;

 @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *") //insert every day at 1:00 AM

 public void reportCurrentTime() throws Exception {
  log.error("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
  //show the date and the time now 

  //variable declaration
  BigInteger planList;
  BigInteger planList2;
  BigInteger Nbpers = new BigInteger("15");
  String color = "red";
  String nom = "groupeTest";

  LocalDateTime dDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-08-03T04:00:00");
  LocalDateTime fDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-08-03T11:30:00");

  String color2 = "blue";
  String nom2 = "groupeTest2";

  LocalDateTime dDate2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-08-03T11:30:00");
  LocalDateTime fDate2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-08-03T19:00:00");


  //insert into the database
  planList = planDao.save(new Plan(color, dDate, fDate, Nbpers, nom, type));

  planList2 = planDao.save(new

   Plan(color2, dDate2, fDate2, Nbpers, nom2, type2));
  List < Plan > list = planDao.getPlan();


  log.error("############Test############");
  //test date incrementation**
  log.error("dDate incremented 1 day : " +
   dDate.plusDays(1));
 }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get the output every day at 1h:00 Am (it's Done) but with the incrementation of the days.

Comment: The `BigInteger` and other stuff seems irrelevant. Simplify you example code to the absolute minimum needed to show your problem. We are here to solve a generalizable problem, not to write the code for your day job for you. See: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Nothing in your example code seems related to your title.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the terrible `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes (now legacy) with their replacement, the *java.time* package. Don’t do that. Avoid the legacy date-time classes entirely.

If you are trying to track actual moments on the timeline, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Your JDBC driver may support only the required `OffsetDateTime` class and not the optional `Instant`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

If you are trying to record some kind of appointment for that same day for certain times of the day, break your `LocalDateTime` into separate pieces: `LocalDate` & `LocalTime`.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.of( 4 , 0 ) ;
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.of( 11, 30 ) ;

LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt1 ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt2 ) ;
```

If you meant the day after, do date math by calling the `plus…` & `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDate dayOfter = odt.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Notice how none of the code above used strings. Rather than wrestle with string manipulations, we used appropriate data types to faithfully represent our intent.

Be aware that if these date-with-time-of-day values are meant to track a specific moment, a specific point on the timeline, **then `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class to be using**. You should be using `ZonedDateTime` with a `ZoneId`. But this is a whole other topic, and one that has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So I'll leave it at that. Search to learn more.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

The body of your question seems entirely unrelated to the title. So I cannot help you with the other part, except to mention that is SQL database we update many rows at once by using an UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause. See [tutorial](http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-update/).

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution is to increment the date and parse the time as text.

```
LocalDateTime date = 
LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(),LocalTime.parse("04:00:00"));
```